# Convert from C# to English

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syntax

I'm trying to understand MVC, and I think I doing quite well. But I met a peculiar syntax which I found from one of MS samples that I cannot decipher! What I would like to know is a translation into English of whats happening such as:
"It is returning an object of type IdentityUser which is passed to a function UserManager bla bla". If you look at the below code it looks like a chain of functions??

```
return new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new UsersDbContext()));
```

any ideas what the above means please anyone?

Comment: are you asking for someone to read the code back to you?

Comment: You could look at the constructors for the classes you are wondering about.  Basically, you are passing a new `UsersDbContext` to the new `UserStore<IdentityUser>`, which you are then passing as a parameter to the new `UserManager<IdentityUser>` constructor.

Comment: ... and those angle brackets are not function calls ... they are so-called generics (or templates) which are some kind of parameterized classes. So UserStore is defined as `UserStore<T>`. You can find those generics for example in lists like `List<String>`

Comment: I guess you'e looking for a C's cdecl for C# :) just joking.

Answer (score 12):

Your question is vague. Instead of answering the question let me describe how I would break this down to understand it.

```
return new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new UsersDbContext()));
```

I would introduce a temporary variable for each sub-expression. So, this is the same as:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new UsersDbContext()));
return userManager;
```

Can we break it down further? Yes.

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new UsersDbContext());
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore );
return userManager;
```

Can we break it down further? Yes.

```
var context= new UsersDbContext();
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context);
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore );
return userManager;
```

Can we break it down further? No.

Is this new program more comprehensible to you? If not, ask a more specific question.

Remember, you can (almost!) always refactor a program such that expressions are assigned to meaningful variables; that's a good technique when you are feeling overwhelmed by the complexity of an expression, because it associated a meaningful label -- an abstraction -- with each part.

Comment: I apologise for being a bit vague. But I was looking exactly at a break down of what's happening. So it's becoming much more clearer that way.  I'm only a bit stuck on the second line now whereby you have 
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context);  
what's is it exactly doing ?

Comment: @deadCrow: To write code samples with angle brackets on StackOverflow you need to surround them with *backticks*.  `<like this>`.  Otherwise it interprets it as an attempt to write an html tag.

Comment: @deadCrow: It is creating an instance of the generic type `UserStore<T>` with type argument `IdentityUser`. If you do not know what generic types are then you need a tutorial on C#'s type system; this isn't the right place to get such a tutorial. Any good beginner book on C# will be able to help you out.

Comment: thank you for your time. I think to have understood... its look like a generic is feeding another generic.  I'm not that usedto that type of syntax. sorry about that

Comment: @deadCrow: Maybe a more intuitive example of feeding a generic to another generic will help? `var listOfList = new List<List<int>>(); listOfList.Add(new List<int>{1,2,3}); listOfList.Add(new List<int>{10,20,30});listOfList[1][2] == 30;`

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new UserManager object you must pass a UserStore as a parameter, but to create a new UserStore object you must pass a UsersDbContext object add a parameter. You're basically constructing all new objects to create the UserManager.

Answer (score 0):

It is creating a new UserManager *generic*. Read more about those beasts (also known as *templates* in C++) here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Generics are like instances, but specialized to handle specific types of objects. If those were regular classes, this line would read `return new UserManager(new UserStore(new UserDbContext()))` , a regular construction of instance of UserManager.

Comment: I note that though generic types are similar -- both in their by-design purpose and their syntax -- to templates, generics are *not* templates. Templates are essentially a fancy copy-paste mechanism, whereas generics are truly part of the type system of the language. There are patterns that you can represent in templates that you cannot represent in generics and vice versa.